# LPC1769 and ATMega88 UART interface

Tags: microcontroller, uart, schematics, level-shifting, lpc1768

I am referring below schematics for implementation.

LPC1769 -- > 3.3V Powered

AtMega88 -- > 5V Powered

LPC1769 UART pins are 5V tolerant. And due to some reason, can't operate AtMega88 on 3.3V supply.

My query is Can I connect UART pins as shown, considering different supplies to both IC's?

[image: Schematics]

One scheme I am thinking, as below:

[image: Proposed scheme]

**Please someone suggest is it correct approach to interface UART ?**

Comment: Diodes are the wrong way around, @filo's answer is correct

Answer (score 2):

Atmega TX -> LPC TX: place a diode (eg. 1N4148) **cathode to Atmega, anode to LPC** and a pullup on LPC side (the when Atmega sends logic high 5V it will be blocked by diode, LPC will see logic high from the pullup, when Atmega sends logic low 0, then it will sink current and LPC will read that as zero).

LPC TX -> Atmega RX: check in the datasheet if LPC lowest output high voltage is higher than Atmega's lowest input high voltage. If yes - just place a series resistor (eg. 1k) for safety in case Atmega RX is ever configured as output high. If not - you will need at least a transistor or level shifter.

Comment: thanks for reply. LPC1769 uart pins  are 5V tolerant. Please check first paragraph, I think something messed there also diode connection seems confusing.

Comment: If they are 5V tolerant than just connect them directly!

Answer (score 0):

Both would work, though suboptimally. I would just put a serial resistor on the line.

Comment: You might explain the problem you see with both. Otherwise, this is sort of short for an answer on Stack Exchange.